# Playing audio from assets flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, mp3, just-audio

Hi I am using just_audio to play a mp3, from what I know to play the audio from url, we can use something like this:

```
UriAudioSource _createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    return AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url']),
      tag: mediaItem,
    );
  }
```

I would like to know is there a way to play it from local assets ?

Comment: check [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/setAsset.html)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 7):

You can use like this

```
var data=await player!.setAsset('assets/mb3.mp3');
```

sets assets in `pubsec.yaml` [Sample Mp3](https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3)

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

[More Information](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#example)

[image]

**SAmpelCode**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

AudioPlayer? player;

void main() {
  player = AudioPlayer();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.home,
      routes: {
        "${AppRoutes.home}": (context) => Home(),
      },
      title: _title,
      // home: ,
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("title")),
      body: const Center(
        child: AudioPlayers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppRoutes {
  static String home = "/";
}

Duration _position = Duration(seconds: 0);
var _progress = 0.0;

class AudioPlayers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioPlayers({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioPlayers> createState() => _AudioPlayersState();
}

class _AudioPlayersState extends State<AudioPlayers> {
  Timer? timer2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: _progress,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    player!.setAsset('assets/mb3.mp3').then((value) {
                      return {
                        _position = value!,
                        player!.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
                          if (state.playing) {
                            setState(() {
                              _progress = .1;
                            });
                          } else
                            switch (state.processingState) {
                              case ProcessingState.idle:
                                break;
                              case ProcessingState.loading:
                                break;
                              case ProcessingState.buffering:
                                break;
                              case ProcessingState.ready:
                                setState(() {
                                  _progress = 0;
                                  timer2!.cancel();
                                });
                                break;
                              case ProcessingState.completed:
                                setState(() {
                                  _progress = 1;
                                });
                                break;
                            }
                        }),
                        player!.play(),
                        timer2 =
                            Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
                          setState(() {
                            _progress += .05;
                          });
                        })
                      };
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    _progress > 0 ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_circle_fill,
                    size: 45,
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 45,
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    player!.stop();
                    timer2!.cancel();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.stop,
                    size: 45,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method to convert your file into url,

```
setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:/your_file.mp3')),
    initialPosition: Duration.zero, preload: true);
```